# Fort Awesome Icon Bigger Than Browser Expects

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons

Using Fort Awesome Icons.

When one of my icons renders, it looks like the browser expects the height to be 90px, but the icon is actually taller, and this causes it to overlap other content that I have.

```
<script src="https://use.fortawesome.com/66d3880d.js"></script>
<br />
<hr />
<i class="fa fa-5x fa-day-sunny-overcast" />
```

[Here is a codepen demonstrating the issue](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/JKgAAy)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I apologise. Firefox developer version behaves differently to chrome/ie/edge and firefox release - yes, there's a clear overlap - sorry for wasting your time

Comment: adding `style="padding-top:10px;"` to the `<i>` fixes it, but I don't like having to do that!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid doing, but it doesn't seem there is any other way

Comment: I'd say it's a bug with that "glyph" - perhaps, as it's a paid product, contact the author, you paid for it, so it should work right :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a less hacky work around

```
.fa-day-sunny-overcast::before {
  font-size:0.88em;
}
```